# Extension of protocol cannot have an inheritance clause

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create filter functionality using Swift. I have many filter types like Location, Skill, etc.
So I'm planning to generalize this using a protocol.

```
protocol FilterProtocol {
    var text: String { get set }
    var count: String? { get set }
    var isSelected: Bool { get set }
}

extension FilterProtocol: Identifiable {
    var id: String  { text }
}

struct LocationFilter: FilterProtocol {
    var text: String
    var count: String?
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

But I am getting error `Extension of protocol 'FilterProtocol' cannot have an inheritance clause`

Comment: Do not make a substantial change to your question after it has already been answered. Simply ask another question

Comment: Can't figure out why sometimes swift allows it and other times it doesn't. I added a protocol extension in a file, built ran with no problem. Moved it to a separate file and then the error :(

Answer (score 2):

Just move the conformance to the declaration:

```
protocol FilterProtocol: Identifiable {
    var text: String { get set }
    var count: String? { get set }
    var isSelected: Bool { get set }
}

extension FilterProtocol {
    var id: String  { text }
}
```

another variant if we consider to make just provided part of code compilable... there might be many variants (depending on final needs and that's out of topic):

```
protocol FilterProtocol {
    var text: String { get set }
    var count: String? { get set }
    var isSelected: Bool { get set }
}

extension FilterProtocol {      // << just extension
    var id: String  { text }
}

struct LocationFilter: FilterProtocol {
    var text: String
    var count: String?
    var isSelected: Bool
}

struct FilterView: View {

    let filters: [FilterProtocol] = []   // << non-generic

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("By Location")
                    .font(.headline)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.circle")
                }
            }
            ForEach(filters, id: \.id) { filter in  // << explicit .id
                HStack {
                    Text(filter.text)
                    Text(filter.count ?? "")

                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi, Error gone but how can I `Equatable` extension, I'm getting error again

Comment: Thank you very much for detail example. without Protocol can I simple make `struct` Implementation, see my Edited Question.

Comment: It would be great if you guide me in this